# How can I prove that following Statements are true or false?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I have to decide whether the following statements are true by using a proof or a counter-example.

$$\begin{align}
&(\text{i})~~~   a < b \text{ and } c < d \Rightarrow ~a - c < b - d\\
&(\text{ii})~~  a < b \text{ and } c < d \Rightarrow ~ac  < bd\\
&(\text{iii})~ a < b \text{ and } c < d \Rightarrow ~ac^2<bd^2
\end{align}$$

I've got following solutions. While I am sure that they are enough, I think that these ones could be "formally cleaner" Both here and on the paper.:

$$\begin{align}
&(\text{i})~~~   a = 1~ b=2~c=-5~d=1 && 1+5 = 6 \not\lt -5-1 = -6 \Rightarrow Statement ~(i)~ is ~false. \\
&(\text{ii})~~  a = 1~ b=2~c=-5~d=-10 && 1*(-5) = -5 \not\lt -2*(-10) = -20 \Rightarrow Statement ~(ii)~ is ~false.\\
&(\text{iii})~ a = 1~ b=2~c=-5~d=1 && 1*5^2 = 6 \not\lt 2*1^2 = 2 \Rightarrow Statement ~(iii)~ is ~false.
\end{align}$$

Comment: You were, yep. I just started studying - do they not mean the same?

Comment: Generally speaking, "$=$" between two algebraic expressions means that those two expressions are equal.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  There have been multiple edits.  I am never sure what to do when edits render comments, or (as here) parts of comments, irrelevant.

Comment: I have deleted some of my earlier comments as subsequent edits have made them irrelevant.  My earliest point still stands, however:  for problems like these, a single counterexample is all you need to invalidate the claim.  You aren't obliged to search for extra assumptions which, were they in place, would make the statements true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one: $1<2\wedge -2<-1$, but $1-(-2)=3 = 2-(-1)$.

The second one: $-2<1\wedge -2<1$, but $(-2)(-2)=4>1 =1\cdot 1$.

The third one: $1<2\wedge -3<-1$, but $1(-3)^2 = 9 > 2 = 2(-1)^2$.